# To get the checkbox value on checking checkbox in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datagridview in which i have fourth column as checkbox.On clicking checkbox i want to get checkbox value in codebehind.Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to access the CheckBox.Checked value directly, rather get the value from whatever it is bound to.

If you really want to get it from the checkbox you can do something like myDataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value